# Insert default value for single field with SQLite

Tags: sqlite

Given the following table in SQLite:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    hair_color VARCHAR NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Green'
)
```

I'm attempting to perform a batch insert, using the default value for `hair_color` for only some of the rows. For example, in PostgreSQL or MySQL, it might look like:

```
INSERT INTO users (name, hair_color) VALUES
    ('Sean', 'Black'),
    ('Tess', DEFAULT)
```

However, SQLite does not provide a `DEFAULT` keyword in any other context beyond `DEFAULT VALUES`. I know that I can do this in two queries as

```
INSERT INTO users (name, hair_color) VALUES ('Sean', 'Black');
INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('Tess');
```

However, I can't imagine that SQLite doesn't provide some mechanism to execute this in a single query. Is there any equivalent to the `DEFAULT` keyword from other backends for SQLite?

Comment: Seems like you have to do two inserts: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html - but thanks for the postgres syntax, didn't know about that.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the specific use case here is an ORM for which I'm adding SQLite support to. It otherwise supports batch inserts, which makes it very difficult to "just do two queries" here. I'm honestly wondering if I can do a subselect which queries the default value out of the schema here, as hacky as that would be.

Comment: Looks like that is the only possibility

Comment: Just from cursory research, it looks like even that might not work. I think the real solution here is to vary the column list when inserting a single record, and disallow batch inserts for SQLite, with the intention of eventually breaking it into multiple statements (it would appear that `sqlite3_prepare_v2` ignores everything after the first semicolon without additional work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite is an embedded database without client/server communication overhead, so there is no technical reason for the database itself to avoid using multiple statements.

It would be possible to create a trigger (for every table) that replaces a special value with the default one.
But this is not possible without knowing the details of the table definition, and the number of rows that could be inserted with a single statement is limited anyway, so the easiest solution is to use one INSERT per row.

Comment: For reference, this led to https://github.com/sgrif/diesel/pull/164 and https://github.com/sgrif/diesel/pull/166. It's unfortunate that we have to jump through these hoops for SQLite, since it's the only database which does not support this. :\